# Union returns dataset - Spark 3.1.2

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, union, databricks

There are two dataframes mergeDF_A and mergeDF_B. The below union action is giving a dataset instead of dataframe. Why is it returning a dataset? And how to get a dataframe?

```
val finalMergeDF = mergeDF_A.union(mergeDF_B).distinct()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert dataset to dataframe using `toDF()`:

```
mergeDF_A.union(mergeDF_B).toDF()
```